# Comparator for generic class. It's possible?

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

Hi guys this is my code to represent a generic tree's node:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {

 T elem;
 TreeNode<T> parent;
 TreeNode<T> child;
 TreeNode<T> sibling;

 .
 .
 .

}
```

and this is the inner class in the main class:

```
public static class ComparatorField implements Comparator<TreeNode>{
 public int compare(TreeNode n1, TreeNode n2) {
 return n1.getElem().compareTo(n2.getElem());
}
```

but when I compile I receive a warning "[rawtypes] found raw type: TreeNode"

I understood that the problem is the  in the TreeNode class but i don't know how make a generic Comparator. For example what I should do if I want use String instead of T ??? I try to write " ... implements `Comparator<TreeNode<T>>` or ... `implements Comparator<TreeNode<?>>` " but nothing... thank you if you want help me

Comment: `class ComparatorField<T> implements Comparator<TreeNode<T>>`.

Comment: If you want to use `compareTo()`, your type parameter needs to extend `Comparable<T>`. The class can then be used with any reference type that implements `Comparable`.

Comment: `public static class ComparatorField` is not an inner class, since in Java an inner class is a nested class that is not `static`, by definition.